# Converting a file directory to JSON

Tags: java, json, algorithm, tree, filesystems

I am using apache commons VFS to create a virtual file system which represents a jar file on my system.

```
fsManager = VFS.getManager();
FileObject jarFile = fsManager.resolveFile("jar:" + path);
FileObject vfs = fsManager.createVirtualFileSystem(jarFile);
```

and I am trying to traverse this convert it into a nested json. Each json object is described as follows:

```
public class DirNode {
      private String id;
      private String path;
      private List<DirNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I am having trouble traversing it. Could you please help me with the algorithm?

Comment: What trouble are you having exactly? Please edit the question and add your code.

Comment: This might be helpful: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_